# How to Bind a Grid Stores to another Grids Column which is a combobox in Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

i have two grids in the same screen for data entry

grid1 has two columns ,column1,column2 which is editable
grid2 has a column which is combobox and need to list the values that were entered in the grid1 column1.

How can this be achieved in Ext Js

Comment: Which version of Ext are you using?

Answer (score 0):

store1:

```
fields:[{
    name:'c1'
},{
    name:'c2'
}]
```

grid1:

```
store:'store1'
columns:[{
    dataIndex:'c1'
},{
    dataIndex:'c2'
}
```

grid2:

```
store: /*NOT store1!*/
columns:[{
    editor:{
        xtype:'combo',
        store:'store1'
        displayField:'c1',
        valueField:'c2'
    }
}]
```